# Neutralization between Ca(OH)2 + H2SO4 in a 30% hydrogen peroxide solution

Tags: acid-base

I have performed an experiment where I added an excess of $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ base to a solution consisting of 5 mL of 30 % hydrogen peroxide (buffered at pH 5) and a very small amount of sulfuric acid (such that the pH of the original solution of 30 % $\ce{H2O2}$ and acid was 1.7).

I am having trouble understanding what reactions maybe occurring between these three substances to give a final pH of 10.5.

I know that $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ and $\ce{H2O2}$ form $\ce{CaO2}$ when reacted, but shouldn't the final pH be equal to that of $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ considering it is in excess? What reactions could be occurring here and why are they not allowing the pH to reach that of $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$?

Any help at all would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no CaO2.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_peroxide Calcium peroxide is produced by combining calcium salts and hydrogen peroxide: Ca(OH)2 + H2O2 → CaO2 + 2 H2O The octahydrate precipitates upon the reaction of calcium hydroxide with dilute hydrogen peroxide. Upon heating it dehydrates.

Comment: All the same, I don't believe it will form in the said conditions.

Comment: It is not the same as "there is no CaO2".

Comment: Let me add that, if pH is 10.5, it's clearly not "neutralized pH". As for the final question, you should read about buffers.

Comment: Nobody express pH with 4 decimal digits, considering effects of activity coefficients. More than 2 digits usually do not make sense to use.

Comment: Is the calcium hydroxide in excess wrt sulphuric acid, or wrt hydrogen peroxide ? As there is neutralisation of the peroxide as the weak acid and precipitation of the salt.

Comment: @Poutnik in excess with respect to sulphuric acid

Comment: pKa of hydrogen peroxide is 12.5  pH 10.5 means the most of it is in its acidic form. That is supported by CaO2 precipitation.

Comment: What method is used to determine pH?

Comment: @JamesGaidis A glass electrode pH meter

Comment: @Poutnik So, the pKa of Hydrogen Peroxide being higher means that the acidic form of the reaction is favored, and so that prevents the solution from reaching the pH of Calcium Hydroxide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your question formulation, you have forgotten to take into account $\ce{H2O2}$ is a weak acid.

The title should rather be:
**Neutralisation between calcium hydroxide and 30% hydrogen peroxide"**

Unless $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ was in excess over $\ce{H2O2}$ - and it was said it was not - $\mathrm{pH}$ would be always significantly lower than pH of the hydroxide.

$$\mathrm{pH}=\mathrm{p}K_  \mathrm{a,\ce{H2O2}} + \log \frac{[\ce{HO2-}]}{[\ce{H2O2}]}$$

where $\mathrm{p}K_  \mathrm{a,\ce{H2O2}}=11.75$$ by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_peroxide?wprov=sfla1), but see the links below.

If we consider reaction

$$\ce{Ca(OH)2 +  H2O2 ->  H2O + Ca(OH)(HO2)}$$

we need to neutralize 50% of $\ce{H2O2}$ to reach $\mathrm{pH}=\mathrm{p}K_  \mathrm{a,\ce{H2O2}}$

The hydroxide forms from $\ce{H2O2}$  the $\mathrm{pH}$ buffer solution of a weak acid and it's salt.

$$\begin{align}
\ce{Ca(OH)2  &<=>> CaOH+  + OH-}\\
\ce{CaOH+ &<=>> Ca^2+  + OH- }\\
\ce{H2O2 &<<=> H+ + HO2-}\\
\ce{H+ + OH- &<=>> H2O}\\
\end{align}$$

$\ce{Ca(OH)2}$: $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b1} =1.37$, $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b2} =2.43$
( Wikipedia )

Additionally, $\ce{HO2-}$ is partially eliminated by precipitation, therefore ratio $ \frac{[\ce{HO2-}]}{[\ce{H2O2}]}$ is kept low and so does $\mathrm{pH}$.

$$\ce{CaOH+ + HO2- + 7 H2O <=>> CaO2 \cdot 8 H2O v}$$

Note also the hydrogen peroxide is weakly acidic even without addition of sulphuric acid and that it's $ \mathrm{p}K_  \mathrm{a}$ depends on $\ce{H2O2}$ concentration.

[H2O2 pH-and-Ionization-Constant](http://www.h2o2.com/technical-library/physical-chemical-properties/thermodynamic-properties/default.aspx?pid=51&name=pH-and-Ionization-Constant)

[The solubility constant of calcium peroxide octahydrate in relation to temperature; its influence on radiolysis in cement-based materials](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022311511008440)

Comment: Does the pKa in the pH equation refer to H2O2 or Ca(OH)2? Thank you.

Comment: H2O2. for Ca(OH)2, there would calcium compounds instead.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much for all of your help.